# Is it possible to configure the spring boot server explicitly?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I've a Spring Boot application where one of the dependencies is using spring and a embedded jetty to start an ad-hoc web server. This causes my spring boot app to start in a jetty instead of a tomcat.

My spring-boot-starter-web:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The dependencies pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is there a possibility to configure the server to use by spring boot explicitly instead of being inferred by the dependency tree?

**EDIT**

I investigated the issue a little bit further and created a repo to reproduce the issue: [github.com/svettwer/spring-server-test](http://github.com/svettwer/spring-server-test)
`org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl` causes spring to start with jetty without any other config required.

**EDIT 2**

The issue is not present anymore in Spring Boot 2.x

**EDIT 3**
I'll deleted the repo mentioned earlier, but here is the dependency setup that caused the issue:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Comment that in to start spring with jetty-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, if you have the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` on your classpath (through `spring-boot-starter-web`), it should always select Tomcat since it has priority over other servlet containers. Even if you have the following dependencies, Spring boot will start with Tomcat:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can programmatically override the chosen servlet container by registering your own `ServletWebServerFactory`, for example:

```java
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory factory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
}
```

You can choose the predefined `TomcatServletWebServerFactory`, `JettyServletWebServerFactory` or the `UndertowServletWebServerFactory`.

Comment: Worked for me! Thx a lot.

Comment: I found out that the `ServletWebServerFactory` definition is not required. Spring boot 2.x solves the problem without the additional bean.

Comment: @SvenHettwer That explains a lot. I also mentioned in the first paragraph that you normally don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

This guide may help you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

If you run an `mvn dependency:tree` and search for `jetty` you might find that you need to exclude it, e.g:

```
spring-boot-starter-jetty
```

excluded like in the example:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- Use Jetty instead -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

which is favouring jetty over tomcat - but you get the idea hopefully...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excluding `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server` would start my application in a tomcat, you're right.
But as I want to make use of the dependencies ad-hoc server capabilities, the jetty-server is required as well.
So both dependencies have to stay for my software to work.

Comment: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration might help you (spring boot 2.x). Perhaps if you  look at the imports at the top (@Import annotation) you'll see they import embedded configs that internally have conditional on missing bean annotations so you might be able to define you own beans to take over configuration perhaps. I think it would seem that tomcat should be favoured over jetty when both are present which is why the example excluded tomcat when jetty is included. How are you determining that jetty is being used over tomcat at runtime?

Comment: Thx for the hint! I'll try this.

`How are you determining that jetty is being used over tomcat at runtime?`
I investigated the issue a little bit further and created a repo to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/svettwer/spring-server-test

org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl causes spring to start with jetty without any other config required.

Comment: Please see Edit 3. It is only a spring boot < 2.x issue. Therefore the it is outdated. Nevertheless, you'll find the dependencies to reproduce attached to the question.